# Preventing one form submission, and submitting another - is this approach reliable?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

Is it safe to - within a submit event handler for one form - submit another form and return `false` to prevent the submission of the first form?

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    $("#form2").submit();
    return false;
});
```

I am using this approach, and it works (in IE6 at least). However, I am concerned that this might not work in other browsers. Could the call to `submit` cancel out the `return false` somehow?

The alternative approach I was considering is

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
    setTimeout('$("#form2").submit();', 10);
    return false;
});
```

....but this might well be adding complexity where none is actually needed.

The reason for needing to do this is that the user is submitting `form1`, but in a certain scenario (which I can detect using JavaScript) this is causing a bug, that can be rectified instead by setting some data in one of `form2`'s fields and then submitting this form instead.

Comment: What if Javascript is disabled?

Comment: If JavaScript is disabled then the user cannot use this website anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work across all browsers, but if you want to be absolutely sure you could do

```
$("#form1").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // cancel the default behavior
    $("#form2").submit();
    return false;
});
```

Using the [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method ensures that you cancel the default behavior **before** doing something that might interfere with it..

Comment: `return false` causes jQuery to do the `.preventDefault()` part.

Comment: @elusive, i know. But the OP is worried if the submit that happens before the `return false`, could somehow interfere with that. It can **not**, but i just point to an alternative that puts that worry at ease (*i hope*)

Answer (score 1):

Your original approach should work everywhere.