# Jquery form.Submit() is not working submit button from another form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two forms.  In the second form I have a button that when clicked is supposed to submit the first form.  Not sure why it is not working.  Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mysubmit').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="get" style="">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" id="form_profile_update" name="form_profile_update">
  <button type="submit" id="mysubmit" class="todo-link btn btn-default emphasis" style="border:none;background-color: #0079BB;color:white;text-transform: uppercase;padding: 15px 20px;margin: 0 auto;display: block;">
                   
                    Connect </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Make it a button Now it submits its own form. `<button type="button"` - also remove the form tags around the second button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing one form submission, and submitting another - is this approach reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193612/preventing-one-form-submission-and-submitting-another-is-this-approach-reliab)

Comment: What are you doing to prevent the second form from being submitted?

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks it worked.  Provide you answer below so I can give you credit

Comment: if you never want the button to submit that form, i don't understand why it is in the form to begin with.

Comment: @Aaron as you're clicking that Button `mysubmit` it's natural behavior is going to submit the form of which the button is a part (nested). Try stopping the natural behavior of the button. using `e.preventDefault();` in your jQuery Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a button Now it submits its own form.

```
<button type="button"
```

also remove the form tags around the second button if it does not need to live in a form

If it must be a submit, then add preventDefault

```
$('#mysubmit').on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel button action
  $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use JavaScript, You can use [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form) attribute to associate the owner form.

> The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a  element in the same document.

```
<button form="myform" type="submit" id="mysubmit" class="todo-link btn btn-default emphasis" >
```

Comment: Never seen that before... Sounds highly unlikely to work in older browsers